# If/else conditional based on categories to choose a freeform form

Tags: categories, conditionals, solspace-freeform

I'm trying to show a contact form based on the category that an entry is a member of, i'm using the freeform plugin to generate forms and then have a category group (an id of 7) with three categories in (ids of 41,42,43).

Here's the current code:

```
           {exp:channel:entries}
             {categories show_group="7"}
                {if "{category_id}" == "42"}
                  {exp:freeform:form form_id="6" return="thanks/index"}
                {/if}
                {if "{category_id}" == "41"}
                  {exp:freeform:form form_id="7" return="thanks/index"}
                {/if}
                {if "{category_id}" == "42"}
                  {exp:freeform:form form_id="8" return="thanks/index"}
                {/if}
              {/categories}
{freeform:all_form_fields}
                    <div class="field-group type-{freeform:field_type} field-{freeform:field_name}">
                      <label>{freeform:field_label}</label>
                      {freeform:field_output}
                    </div>
                  {/freeform:all_form_fields}
                  <p>{freeform:submit}</p>
              {/exp:freeform:form}
            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

This however is simply trying to output all three forms and only showing the first one on every page no matter which categories they are assigned to. Any ideas how I should go about this? I'm guessing it's parsing the freeform tag before the conditional at the moment but not sure how to fix it?

Comment: Please, update your question. Where is the closing tag of freeform?

Comment: Hi, I have the following beneath the categories but it's not really relevant to my question:

Comment: This made a lot of difference to my answer, actually.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure all data of `exp:channel:entries` is parsed before `exp:freeform`. This is almost exactly the point of the [sample code in docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/plugins.html#changing-parsing-order) about `parse="inward"`.

Try this, please:

```
{exp:channel:entries parse="inward"}
    {categories show_group="7"}
        {if "{category_id}" == "42"}
            {exp:freeform:form form_id="6" return="thanks/index"}
        {if:elseif "{category_id}" == "41"}
            {exp:freeform:form form_id="7" return="thanks/index"}
        {if:elseif "{category_id}" == "42"}
            {exp:freeform:form form_id="8" return="thanks/index"}
        {/if}
    {/categories}
                {freeform:all_form_fields}
                    <div class="field-group type-{freeform:field_type} field-{freeform:field_name}">
                    <label>{freeform:field_label}</label>
                    {freeform:field_output}
                    </div>
                {/freeform:all_form_fields}
                <p>{freeform:submit}</p>
            {/exp:freeform:form}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This code just works because all conditionals are related to `exp:channel:entries`, so they can be parsed in the right order.

I changed the conditionals to `elseif` to prevent the case of some user to chose more than one category.

Comment: Can you use parse="inward" on the entries tag? Isn't it meant to be used on plugin tags?

Comment: couldn't get this working, ended up having to use an embed: {embed="site/_application-form" category_id="{categories show_group="7"}{if category_id == "42"}6{/if}{if category_id == "41"}7{/if}{if category_id == "46"}8{/if}{/categories}"}

Comment: Is there something to do with the fact that your code checks for category_id 42 twice? I just noted this.

Comment: Nick, can you post your solution as an answer?